# Mustache.js within Django template not working

Tags: javascript, django, mustache

I want to `render` ajax response with [Mustache.js](https://mustache.github.io/) but for some reason, variables inside templates aren't displayed. I modified Mustache's delimiter but it still isn't working.

> .js

```
/*
 * Get reservation preview snippet.
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
    Mustache.tags = ['<%', '%>'];
    var tableRows = $("#table-wrapper table tr");

    // table row was clicked
    tableRows.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        var previewURL = $(this).find("#ajax_id").attr('data-id');

        // get preview and load it to template
        $.getJSON(previewURL, function(reservation) {
            console.log("Updated at: " + reservation.updated_at);
            var template = $('#reservationPreviewTpl').html();
            var html = Mustache.render(template, reservation);
            console.log('HTML' + html);
            $('#test123').html(html);
        });

    });
```

> template

```
<div id="test123"></div>
<script id="reservationPreviewTpl" type="text/template">
<h1>I am a template</h1>
<p><% reservation.updated_at %></p>
</script>
```

> Console output

[image]

Comment: @andlrc: I've updated the question, `reservation.updated_at` seems to be working though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `reservation.updated_at` should just be `updated_at`

> template

```
<div id="test123"></div>
<script id="reservationPreviewTpl" type="text/template">
<h1>I am a template</h1>
<p><% updated_at %></p>
</script>
```